# system doesn't invoke /bin/sh

Tags: exploit, libc, rop

I am learning libc shellcode attacks and trying to execute /bin/sh from system

I can execute other commands from system like whoami and ls -a but can not run /bin/sh

the following works

```
string = b"ls -a\0"
# system, _exit, system arg 
b'\xf0\xef\x04\x08', b'\xe3\xd0\x06\x08', string_addr.to_bytes(4, byteorder='little')
```

but this doesn't work

```
string = b"/bin/sh\0"
# system, _exit, system arg 
b'\xf0\xef\x04\x08', b'\xe3\xd0\x06\x08', string_addr.to_bytes(4, byteorder='little')
```

what is going wrong here?

Comment: I tried to open stdin by open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_TRUNC|O_APPEND|O_ASYNC) and "</dev/stdin" but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context ? Have you check existence of /bin/sh ? Did you try to run "sh" without exact location just as you did for "ls" ?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not working or that stdin is just being closed immediately?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I am aware of this stdin issue, I tried executing it in various ways like this "/bin/sh -c \"(cat input ; cat -)\"\0" to pass the stdin but it doesn't help.

Comment: Crosspost https://security.stackexchange.com/q/239439/90657

Comment: See my comment on your other question.